# What actually happens when adamantium strikes adamantium?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, adamantium

In the *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* movie, when Wolverine escaped after the experiment, he took shelter in the house of an old couple. Inside the house, when he touches his blades in the washroom, they produce a spark. In the same movie, William Stryker uses adamantium bullets to penetrate his skull and knock him unconscious.

- Can adamantium really cut adamantium?
- If adamantium really cuts itself, is the bullet still inside wolverine's brain?

Comment: Since the physics for such an impossible material have not been properly debated, we cannot draw any true conclusions. But the writers for that movie epic-failed by needing an adamantium bullet in the first place. A bullet through Wolverine's ocular cavity would have done the same thing (scrambled his brain) and could have been made of just lead...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Wolverine have a hole in his forehead?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12600/does-wolverine-have-a-hole-in-his-forehead)

Comment: The original question claims it was a "vibranium bullet", but Stryker specifically said "adamantium" in the movie and the game version of it.

Comment: @Thaddeus: Are Wolverine's orbits not coated with adamantium?

Comment: His orbits might be but they are surely less durable than his skull, designed to absorb impact. Shoot him through his eyes and the region behind there should be weak enough to allow a bullet to penetrate his skull.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### In the Comics

- In the comics, when adamantium strikes adamantium, nothing happens. They look awesome, they make sparks, coolness ensues, other solutions must be found.
- Captain America's shield and Wolverine's claws have clashed several times historically. They made sparks, nothing more.

[image]

- Most times in the comic medium adamantium is irresistible, for cutting through things or unbreakable for defending against things.

#### In the Movies

- Depending on who made the movie, Marvel's movie canon is all over the map, mostly because the writers don't understand the material well enough to write it effectively.
- In the Wolverine movie, an adamantium (assumingly armor-piercing) round meets Wolverine's adamantium-laced skeleton, the propelled bullet wins.
- The round penetrated his skull and presumably exited out the back. Or we are forced to imagine his body finding a painful and unpleasantly graphic means of removing the round from his body.

#### Off the Record

- Since the physics for such an impossible material have not been properly debated, we cannot draw any true conclusions.
- But the writers for that movie epic-failed by needing an adamantium bullet in the first place. A bullet through Wolverine's ocular cavity would have done the same thing (scrambled his brain) and could have been made of just lead...

Imagine the cost savings. Buying overpriced bullets - your government at work.

Comment: +1 For bureaucracy at its finest.  Even in a comic book movie.

Comment: The Adamantium-plus mentioned in your frame there is because the shield is an Adamantium-Vibranium blend so it's not 100% answering the question, the Vibranium will absorb a lot of the kinetic energy

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Apparently Adamantium can't cut through Adamantium.

From wolverine first class #5