# Are the adamantium rules from previous Wolverine movies now not canon after "Logan"?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, canon, logan, adamantium

In *Logan*, we see that

> the Logan clone is killed by X-23 with an Adamantium bullet to the head.

But in previous Wolverine movies,

- *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*  Adamantium bullets did not kill Wolverine
- *The Wolverine* the Silver Samurai had to have super heated Adamantium to damage Logan's Adamantium skeleton.

So is the canon from *Logan* rewriting the nature of Adamantium and thus overwriting previous canon information about Adamantium?

Comment: All we know for sure is that it stopped moving.  The brain could have been slowly regenerating and the thing might have gotten up a few days later.

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13498/should-the-adamantium-bullets-have-worked-on-wolverine , http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79236/can-wolverine-be-decapitated-by-an-adamantium-based-weapon?rq=1 , http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42756/what-actually-happens-when-adamantium-strikes-adamantium?rq=1 , http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16328/why-cant-adamantium-cut-through-vibranium?rq=1

Comment: X-Men Origins Wolverine was already taking liberties with how adamantium worked compared two X men 1 through 3.
In X1 there is no traces of bullets holes in logan skull (we see X rays)
In X2 a bullet to the head knocks Logan off for a few seconds, but in Origins, it just bounces off

Comment: Related: [Why didn't X-24 regenerate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/70449/1799)

Answer (score 12):

Not necessarily, and not all of it. X-Men continuity is tricky.

In general, it's hard to reconcile the X-Men Cinematic Universe together no matter which movies you use. *Origins: Wolverine* contradicts a lot of things, *Days of Future Past* reboots things, etc. In this case, there were vague and contradictory statements abounding about *Logan*, some implying that it was its own universe, others that it followed directly from *Days of Future Past*'s end scene, etc.

One thing we *do* know is that Fox does not consider *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* to be canon anymore. Fox executives went on record as saying that, part of the motivation for *Days of Future Past* was to try and "clean up" some of the continuity mess that *Origins* had left. So we can ignore the fact that an adamantium bullet only injured Logan but killed X-24.

How to reconcile *The Wolverine* and *Logan* isn't as clear, but again, the situations aren't exactly the same. The Samurai was trying to slice through Logans claws with his own blades; a bullet fired at close range has much more power behind it, and is already heated from the gunpowder.

We also don't *know* that X-24 has exactly the same adamantium structure as Logan; perhaps Alkali decided to leave a few Achilles Heels in him just in case he ran amok the way Logan did.

As a whole, there may be *parts* of prior movies that we have to erase or explain away as non-canon anymore, but the general [timeline of events](https://moviepilot.com/p/post-logan-x-men-timeline/4220996) and the characters that took part in them is still mostly intact.

Comment: There have been a few interviews now where Mangold has basically said that he didn't concern himself too much with continuity, and the fact that Fox didn't mention something as glaring as the Caliban issue to either director indicates that they're not really all that concerned either.

Comment: @phantom42 got any links to that?

Comment: @jared [here you go](https://is.gd/DesW2P) "In order to make a different Logan, and a different tone of a Wolverine movie, we felt like we couldn’t hold on to every tradition established in all the movies religiously, or we’d be trapped by the decisions made before us"

Comment: [and](https://moviepilot.com/p/logan-james-mangold-caliban-x-men-universe-continuity-error/4223817) “It’s a funny, messy story of how so often these things are not as coordinated as everyone thinks. I actually had written him into our movie, and they didn’t know [he was] in Apocalypse, and then they kind of wrote it in their movie, and they cast someone in their movie and I had not seen it and was working away on mine.”

Comment: There's a better one floating about too, but my google-fu is failing me at the moment.

Comment: In Logan, Wolverine was certain that he would get killed by that bullet. But maybe, it's because he was sick.

Comment: In order to further back up your statement that the movie continuity is all over the place, Jean very clearly uses Phoenix-level powers in 1983 (X-Men: Apocalypse), yet hasn't even gained them until 1992 (Dark Phoenix)