# How did this bullet pass through Wolverine's Adamantium-covered skull?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, adamantium, x-men-2

Wolverine's whole body has an Adamantium layer underneath his skin. Adamantium is an indestructible metal, as shown in *X-Men: The Last Stand* but in *X-Men 2* a policeman shoots Wolverine in the face, outside Bobby's house. The bullet appears to pass through the Adamantium skeleton and kill Wolverine (at least for a couple of minutes).

**How did the bullet pass through the Adamantium layer?**

Comment: "Wolverine's whole body has a Adamantium layer underneath his skin" Aren`t his bones covered resp. didn`t his bones react with the adamantium? The skull is a large bone more or less directly under the skin, that´s why in ths case it`s nearly the same, but the rest is another story.

Comment: "Wolverine's whole body has a Adamantium layer underneath his skin." No, it doesn't. His *bones* are covered.

Comment: @phantom42: I believe, at least in the comics, that most of his bones aren’t even covered with adamantium; rather, [they’re infused with it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7986/why-doesnt-the-adamantium-bone-covering-kill-wolverine?rq=1).

Comment: -1, because this question is based on not one but two false premises: Firstly, that Wolverine has an "adamantium layer under his skin", and secondly that the bullet in X2 passed through his skeleton. Did the OP even watch the scene in question? The bullet clearly pops out of his forehead skin as it heals.

Comment: Wolverine is not "dead" in that scene, he is just unconscious due to *the impact of a bullet to his forehead*. I'm sorry but this question is so poorly formed as to be un-salvageable.

Comment: @user30031 - I beg to differ. Although the question is based on a mistaken premise, that doesn't make it a bad question. Making it a smidge more specific brings it into closer focus.

Comment: @Valorum normally I would agree, but this question is based on *several* mistaken premises which renders the question moot. However, an interesting set of answers has appeared, even though think they take a bit of liberty where the question is concerned.

Comment: It's not just mistaken premise, it's sort of the definition of "poorly researched". The scene in the movie, shown in the question itself, is VERY different than what is described in the question. Notable: Valorum added the video which makes the validity of the question look even worse.

Comment: @user30031 I think it's fairly obvious what the OP was asking, and the 'false premises' are simply misunderstandings by the OP leading to their confusion and thus to the actual question.

Comment: Hollywood, that's how. Or it was made of super-adamantium, either way it's voodoo.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Wolverine was shot in the head and he is knocked out, but to me it clearly looks like the bullet is sitting in his head in the video in your question. As his skin heals, the bullet pops out. (Valorum's answer confirms this with a quote from the novelization.)

So the bullet does not look like it passed through his Adamantium-bonded skull. And if it had, and his brain was damaged by the bullet, he would have suffered memory loss after the brain regenerated. This happened in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* when Stryker shot him with two Adamantium bullets (or Vibranium, possibly). In *X2*, there is no memory loss because the bullet did not damage his brain.

Wolverine's Adamantium skull could have two bullet holes in it from Stryker's Adamantium bullets ([see this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12609/67849)), so he could perhaps get damaged by a regular bullet at the exact same spot now, if he was extremely unlucky. However, according to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/13762/23384) the Adamantium plating on his skull could have regenerated as well. In any case, the regular bullet in *X2* clearly did not hit the same spot. Compare the Adamantium bullet holes in the first picture with the regular bullet "hole" in the second:

[image]

[image]

Anyway, the answer to the title of your question is "no". Normal bullets do not go through Adamantium.

Comment: Watched *True Blood* recently and was really confused why Sookie was looking at Logan, then thought it was photoshopped because the difference in skin color... Jeez, the X-Men movies were long ago.

Comment: @NickT Made my day :D

Answer (score 35):

[Read the first couple paragraphs here.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/XMenOriginsWolverine)

TL;DR: The bullet did not penetrate the adamantium layer, he's just been hit in the skull by a lump of metal traveling at probably something over 1,000 feet per second, which is why he got knocked out which seems the most plausible explanation.  The bullet was just embedded in the flesh that's around his skull.

Comment: `he's just been hit in the skull by a lump of metal traveling at probably something over 1,000 feet per second` - there's a good chance he got a nasty concussion, too.

Comment: a normal person would have one, but i think his healing factor would negate that

Comment: He probably got a concussion, then healed from it.  Healing an injury =/= not receiving the injury

Comment: @fyrepenguin. Wolverine doesn't scar when his healing factor closes an open wound.  By that same logic, I wouldn't expect a concussion to leave a lasting effect.

On an unrelated note, the newest Logan movie (which I haven't seen) would probably be terrible Wolverine did suffer any long term effects from TBI's.

Comment: @ABailey I wouldn't expect it to last too long, but there are immediate effects of concussions as well (like a headache or loss of consciousness).

Answer (score 11):

The film's [official novelisation](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_2_(novelization)) confirms that the bullet, although penetrating the skin and breaking into pieces, didn't (and couldn't) penetrate his impenetrable adamantium skull. He's not dead, merely unconscious.

> She yelled at him some more, partly to purge her own terror, but most
>   of all to keep attention away from Logan. **She knew the adamantium
>   interlaced with his skeletal structure meant that his bones couldn’t
>   be broken. All that bullet had likely done, aside from breaking the
>   skin—which was decidedly messy—was give him a royal headache.** More
>   importantly, though, his healing factor would be speedily dealing with
>   both the wound and the headache. She didn’t know what he could do once
>   he recovered, but it would be one more asset than the kids had right
>   now.

and

> Logan’s eyes fluttered as the shattered remains of the officer’s
>   bullet fell from the healing wound. Rogue was right; his head was
>   murder. This was a great power, no argument there.